# django runserver error "Secure Connection Failed An error occurred during a connection to 192.168.99.100:8000. PR_END_OF_FILE_ERROR"

Tags: django, docker

I'm working on a Django project that cloned from git, i use docker container, that is all run well but when i start Django local sever , I 'm faced to this errors. I don't know how to define the cause, is there anyone have been facing one similar, looking forward to a response. thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 2):

you might have to use http://192.168.99.100:8000 instead of https://192.168.99.100:8000

Comment: Thank @Smeh Ramandan, ordinarily, I also use https://192.168.99.100:8000. But it does not work

Comment: Cause firefox redirects you to https try chrome or remove the s manually and check your allowed hosts but am sure that the https blocks the connection you can read more about ssl

Comment: Make sure you are not redirected to https

Comment: I have try but it does not work for fire fox, chrome is work but only for  192.168.99.100:8000/sub-page not  192.168.99.100:8000 (main-index_page)